# Installing tensorflow 1.x on Google colab (december 2022)

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow1.15

I have custom google colab notebooks that require `tensorflow-gpu==1.15`. To install such version, last week I only had to run a cell containing

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

and its output logs were

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.15
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (411.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 411.5 MB 7.6 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.49.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.2.0)
Collecting gast==0.2.2
  Downloading gast-0.2.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (0.2.0)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
  Downloading tensorflow_estimator-1.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 503 kB 63.7 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (3.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.21.6)
Collecting tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0
  Downloading tensorboard-1.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.8 MB 55.0 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (0.37.1)
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.8
  Downloading Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 50 kB 5.7 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from h5py->keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow-gpu==1.15) (1.5.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: gast
  Building wheel for gast (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for gast: filename=gast-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl size=7554 sha256=a5728d08759da6f77f4c796ce360966bd8d1f9c0387c6844eb86294c922c0025
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/21/7f/02/420f32a803f7d0967b48dd823da3f558c5166991bfd204eef3
Successfully built gast
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-estimator, tensorboard, keras-applications, gast, tensorflow-gpu
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow-estimator
    Found existing installation: tensorflow-estimator 2.8.0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-estimator-2.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-estimator-2.8.0
  Attempting uninstall: tensorboard
    Found existing installation: tensorboard 2.8.0
    Uninstalling tensorboard-2.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorboard-2.8.0
  Attempting uninstall: gast
    Found existing installation: gast 0.5.3
    Uninstalling gast-0.5.3:
      Successfully uninstalled gast-0.5.3
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.8.2+zzzcolab20220929150707 requires tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8, but you have tensorboard 1.15.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.8.2+zzzcolab20220929150707 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.9,>=2.8, but you have tensorflow-estimator 1.15.1 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-probability 0.16.0 requires gast>=0.3.2, but you have gast 0.2.2 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed gast-0.2.2 keras-applications-1.0.8 tensorboard-1.15.0 tensorflow-estimator-1.15.1 tensorflow-gpu-1.15.0
```

and it worked perfectly. However, today I ran the very same command and I got

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15
```

Does google colab not support `tensorflow-gpu==1.15` anymore?

I also tried to first uninstall the current tensorflow version but did not work either.

**EDIT**: As @Hiedrass pointed out, you can get it by following the instructions from: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3266#issuecomment-1348660900

Comment: Right now, Google Colab Notebooks are running with Python 3.8. Thats why you cant install tensorflow 1.15. Tensorflow 1.15 works with Python 3.7 .

Comment: @Hiedrass, thanks for the suggestion.  I downgraded the python version to `3.6.9` and installed `tensorflow-gpu==1.15`.  Now the problem is that when I import it and check its version I get `tensorflow==2.9.2`.

Comment: I am currently dealing with the same problem. I couldn't find the solution. The kernel remains in python 3.8 and we need to update it too, but I couldn't find how to do it :(

Comment: Check this comment. Its working. https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3266#issuecomment-1348660900